# Как загрузить галерею изображений в фрагменте?

Tags: java, android

Есть фрагмент, есть ImageButton. При нажатии на кнопку должна открываться галлерея, где я могу выбрать изображение, далее это изображение загружается в ImageButton.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При нажатии на ImagButton в фрагменте пишем следующий код:

```
 imageButtonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

Далее в активности переопределяем метод **onActivityResult()** и пишем:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST){


        Uri fileUri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(),fileUri);
            imageButtonTest.setImageBitmap(photo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```